# howtographql + React tutorial : Error: Cannot find module './generated/prisma.graphql'

Tags: reactjs, graphql, prisma-graphql

I'm following the howtographql + React tutorial right now. I'm currently at the beginning of the tutorial when I have to define my queries, mutation and stuff in my `schema.graphql`. But according to the tutorial, I have to import prisma.graphql from the `generated`folder by writing the following line :

`# import Link, Vote, LinkSubscriptionPayload, VoteSubscriptionPayload from "./generated/prisma.graphql"`

I indeed generated the `server`folder which contains everything except this file that is supposed to be generated as well I guess.

Apparently, I should be able to run the server using `yarn start`but when I'm doing so, I have this message :

```
Error: Cannot find module './generated/prisma.graphql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:609:15)
    at resolveFileName (/Users/hamza/tfeScreen/reactapp/react-apollo/server/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:29:39)
    at resolveFrom (/Users/hamza/tfeScreen/reactapp/react-apollo/server/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:43:9)
    at module.exports (/Users/hamza/tfeScreen/reactapp/react-apollo/server/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:46:41)
    at resolveModuleFilePath (/Users/hamza/tfeScreen/reactapp/react-apollo/server/node_modules/graphql-import/dist/index.js:150:24)
    at /Users/hamza/tfeScreen/reactapp/react-apollo/server/node_modules/graphql-import/dist/index.js:187:30
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at collectDefinitions (/Users/hamza/tfeScreen/reactapp/react-apollo/server/node_modules/graphql-import/dist/index.js:185:16)
    at Object.importSchema (/Users/hamza/tfeScreen/reactapp/react-apollo/server/node_modules/graphql-import/dist/index.js:73:14)
    at mergeTypeDefs (/Users/hamza/tfeScreen/reactapp/react-apollo/server/node_modules/graphql-yoga/dist/index.js:412:37)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...
Do you guys have any idea ?

Comment: Can you share your `prisma.yml` ?

Comment: `endpoint: 'myEndPointUrl'

datamodel: datamodel.prisma

  - generator: javascript-client
    output: ../src/generated/prisma-client
hooks:
  post-deploy:
    - prisma generate`

Comment: `prisma.graphql` is a file that you create by yourself, it's not generated

Comment: Probably but it seems like there isn't a place in the tutorial where they say that I have to create it or even what to add in there..